# Rails submit_tag form validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In my view I have:

## event.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group registration_form">
            <%= form_tag(register_learner_path, {remote: true}) do -%>
              <p>
              <%= label_tag :email %>
              <%= text_field_tag :email %>
              <p/>
              <p>
              <%= label_tag "First Name" %>
              <%= text_field_tag :first_name %>
              <p/>
              <p>
              <%= label_tag "Last Name" %>
              <%= text_field_tag :last_name %>
              <p/>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'event_id', @event.id %>
              <p class="submit_register">
              <%= submit_tag "Register for this event", id: 'register_button', :onclick => "return validateform();" %>
                  <span class="help-block">Enter your name and email above and the link will be magically revealed</span>
              <p/>
            <%- end -%>
          </div>
```

...and my coffeescript is:

## events.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    if $('div').hasClass 'form-group registration_form'
        $(".location").hide()
        $(".location-section-link").hide()
        $(".submit_register").click ->
            validateForm()
            if validateEmail($("#email").val()) == false
                alert('Please enter a valid email address')
                return false
            else
                $(".location").show()
                $(".location-section-link").show()
                $(".registration_form").hide()

    #validate email
    validateEmail = (email) ->
      re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
      re.test email

    #validate email, first name and last name
    validateForm = ->
        if $("#email").val() == '' || $("#first_name").val() == '' || $("#last_name").val() == ''
                alert('Please enter first name, last name, and email')
                return false
```

Essentially I am trying to accomplish two validations here. One I want to ensure no empty strings in email, first name and last name. Second, I want to verify a 'valid' email based on the regex in the js.

The behavior I am seeing with this code is that both the validations are running, however I only want the email validation to run IF the other validation (test of empty strings) passes.

Comment: `$('div').hasClass 'form-group registration_form'` is just plain weird. You select every `div` on the page and then filter them, thats horrible for performance. Use `$group = $('.form-group.registration_form')` `if $group.length`

Comment: @papirtiger Just to sanidty check https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/5f2b61f2d3b66441824a

Comment: Better. Also [`submit_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag) creates a `<input type="submit" />`  element which does not have content, it only has a value attribute which specifies the text, what you want is [`button_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag). And get rid of the onclick attribute while you are at it.

Comment: Ah sorry ignore that last comment, I was just thrown off by the code indentation.

Comment: `if !validateForm() return false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this feels a little busy, but it works. Feel free to make suggestions...

```
jQuery ->
    $group = $('.form-group.registration_form')
    if $group.length
        $(".location").hide()
        $(".location-section-link").hide()
        $(".submit_register").click ->
            if validateForm() == false
                return false
            else if validateEmail($("#email").val()) == false
                alert('Please enter a valid email address')
                return false
            else
                $(".location").show()
                $(".location-section-link").show()
                $(".registration_form").hide()

    #validate email
    validateEmail = (email) ->
      re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
      re.test email

    #validate email, first name and last name
    validateForm = ->
        if $("#email").val() == '' || $("#first_name").val() == '' || $("#last_name").val() == ''
                alert('Please enter first name, last name, and email')
                return false
```

Comment: What if you moved the email alert to the email function, and did this `if !validateForm || !validateEmail($('#email').val()) return false` it validates in order, so if `validateForm` returns `false`, it becomes true and `validateEmail` is not run, and we return `false`, causing the form to not submit. if `vForm` is `true`, it becomes `false` and `vEmail` is checked, if both return `true` and are flipped, the `return false` is not executed and the form continues normally.